# Unproportional keyboard on landscape layout Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am having EditText in my LinearLayout. **When i am typing text in portrait mode keyboard displays fine but when i changed to landscape mode , only i can editext box and a button on right side of it, that looking really bad.**

Just i want to look the keyboard same in both modes.

How i achieve that??

**Problem is:**  `Keyboard is filling the entire screen am not able to see other views in the screen in landscape when i want to type text..`

Thanks

Comment: Not really sure what your problem is with the appearance in the second case? The shape of the soft keyboard? The position of the soft keyboard? Consider looking at several questions on stack overflow addressing the hiding and properties of the soft keyboard.

Comment: Keyboard is filling the entire screen am not able to see other views in the screen in landscape when i want to type text..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In  layout at landscape, you can set android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi" for edittext