# why keyboard in Landscape mode appear like this?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a problem with showing keyboard in landscape mode. My activity contains an `EditText` where user must type a license number, and a `Button` ok. It looks like this (image is rotated) [image: enter image description]
. I put the following code to appear the keyboard when activity starts :

```
imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
imm.showSoftInput(this.licenseText,InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

and now my activity starts like this (image is rotated) : [image: enter image description]

My question is : why it looks like this? If it is in portrait mode, the keyboard appear on the bottom side but not affect the contain of current view. I put the `EditText` on the top side for this, to appear the keyboard on bottom. Can anyone explain me why this looks like this or if i can change this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi".

This sounds like the same issue discussed in [Unproportional keyboard on landscape layout Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759539/unproportional-keyboard-on-landscape-layout-android)

Answer (score 0):

The answer which gave by @Frank was right but you can do programmatically by this:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```